# Storing SVG settings in a global variable to retain its contents during resize - acceptable?

Tags: javascript, globals

In the solution I've been asked to maintain (Meteor based app), there are several responsive SVG charts. When the page is loaded, settings for each chart are stored using the following:

```
  <input type='text' id='chartA' style='display:none' value='{{settingsChartA}}'>
```

Then, when the window is resized, there is no current view so the data SVG data are loaded from this value:

```
if (Blaze.currentView && Template.currentData()) {
        let currentData = Template.currentData();
        if (currentData) {
            settings = ....
        }
    } else {  //WHEN THERE IS NO VIEW, USED STORED DATA
        let s = $('#chartA').val();
        if (s) {
            settings = JSON.parse(s);
        }
    }
    return settings;
```

I'm now wondering, why not use a global variable, isnt it much simpler? It would be set and read the same way as the input field above. Am I missing some obvious drawback / issues?